# Database Log file Backup

Tags: sql-server

I was wondering if the Database Backup .bak Contain the Log file.

i found that the space different between the database and backup is form the locked space for the database.
but i didn't found any related posts that says if the log file is in the backup file.

Answer (score 8):

No it isn't. Or at least not in its entirety.

Part of the transaction log will be included though reflecting concurrent activity during the backup. This is to allow the database to be restored to a transactionally consistent state.

Much more detail in this article by Paul Randal [Understanding SQL Server Backups](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.07.sqlbackup.aspx)